# Linq query returns values instead of setting values (With example) in C#

Tags: c#, linq, list

```
var values = new List<Double>();
```

/*
Fill values with large set (4500 data points or more) of data
*/

What I want to do is set the value of every third data point to a random float. Just assume that RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0) works fine The problem is that the following linq query seems to be returning a list of these data points instead of changing the values in my list values. How can I accomplish this?

```
values
  .Where(x => x % 3 == 0)
  .ToList()
  .ForEach(i => i = (double)(RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0)));
```

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use a simple loop?

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead (assigning to `values[index]` will update the list).

Comment: 'd prefer a simple loop, too. Remember that LINQ is a _functional_ programming framework. It's whole intention is to _return values/sets out of other values_ and _not_ to cause side effects. afaik the "Q" stands for _query_, there's no "A" for action in "LINQ".

Comment: @RenéVogt Not only that, but the example in the iterates 3 times instead of once.

Comment: I wanted to try to do this using linq because I thought it would be a fun exercise and help me understand more about linq. Boy was I right!!! :)

Edit: That is a beautiful way to put that Rene Vogt! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The list is a one of a `double` which is a primitive data type in .NET. So the `i` in the `ForEach` will be a copy of the initial value and setting it won't change the real value in the list.

You'll have to use a good old `for` for this.

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    if (i % 3 == 0)
    {
        values[i] = RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0);
    }
}
```

You can also use `i+=3` if that's all you need:

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i+=3)
{
    values[i] = RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0);
}
```

Other data types like structs are also copied by value, these are value data types in .Net.

Comment: You can use `i+=3` and omit the %-check

Comment: This is exactly what I did on my first pre-linq attempt. As put by Rene Vogt, it is a querying language, not and action language. :)

Comment: What a nice way to put it. LINQ is a query language, not an action one.

Comment: I am making this answer, not because it told me how to use linq to do this, but because it, along with the comments to my question, illustrated the proper way to think about linq.

Answer (score 1):

Either a simple and efficient for-loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.Count; i+=3)
{
    values[i] = (double)RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0);
}
```

or:

```
values = values
   .Select((x, index) => index % 3 != 0 ? x : (double)RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: Can I suggest you use the `Select((i, x)=> i % 3 ` overload, so you are not `%` on a double. They also did not state the list was pre-populated with the index.

Comment: This was my exact first attempt! :) I wanted to give linq a try but perhaps it is not appropriate here. :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all `ForEach` is not linq.
Second when you call `ToList()` you are creating a new list so changes in it wont be reflected in original list (`values`).

You can simply do it with a for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.Count; i++)
{
    if (values[i] % 3 == 0)
        values[i] = (double)(RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0));
}
```

Comment: Interesting! I have always thought of the ForEach method on a list as a linq expression but, as I see now, it is not an extension method of IEnumerable! The second part was explained in this post as: LINQ... not LINA  (Query not Action!) :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`x => x % 3 == 0` This does not get every third item, but select items that are exactly divisible by 3. And to be honest I'd have to look up how `%` behaves with doubles, I think it returns a double and then you would not want to compare two doubles with `==`.

But as you have not stated the list is pre-populated, just that you want every 3rd item to be randomized:

```
values = values
   .Select((x, idx) => idx % 3 != 0 ? x : (double)RandomUtils.RandomFloat(1.0))
   .ToList();
```

Comment: I see what you are doing. I used it but it didn't work. The values were skewed to the far left! When I use a simple loop, it works.... hm... This looks so promising!!!

Comment: Well at one point I did have `(x, idx)` in the wrong order. Make sure it's that order.